# Should I use mobile shader if not necessary in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

For some time I'm creating simple google cardboard vr game. It's one of my first games so I probably dot know many things. My problem is that i was uing standard shader  all the time, but recently I noticed that there is mobile shader available. Then when I was browsing through Unity's standard assets i found `AutoMobileShaderSwitch` script(I suppose it switches between shaders depending on the platform). The thing is that I have been using standard shader all the time and it worked just fine(on my phone).

Is there any reason to use this moblie shader in this case. Maybe it will increase performance sginificatly? Aleso do you know what shoul I do with this `AutoMobileShaderSwitch` script? Should I just attach it to any gameobject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually what you do is to develop with **standard** shaders. Don't worry about mobile shaders until you are about to **release** for mobiles, then you **switch** the shaders to mobile. By doing this, you will know that the images you see during developing is the **highest** quality of what your game would look like.

Also, when making your game, always check for the **framerate** once in a while, on your mobile device. If it gets down to something you consider to be **unacceptable** for your game, then you can **switch** the shader to **mobile** and see if that makes a **difference** before spending time, optimizing you code.

And yes, mobile shaders will **improve** performance, especially when using **transparent** shaders. Mobile shaders are **optimized** for **mobile** devices. Basically, things were **stripped** out from them to make them **faster** and **lighter** on mobile devices. The **down** part of this is that some mobile shaders **don't** look **good** like the **standard** ones because things were **removed**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will probably use this moblie shader because in vr every frame counts :D Do you know what should I do with this `AutoMobileShaderSwitch`script(do I have to do anything else than just attaching it to empty gameobject)?

Comment: Ok nevermind I think I misunderstood how this script works.

Comment: I have not used that before and I don't know how it works. Maybe attach it to gameobject or put it in the Editor folder. It looks like there is a button  you press to change the shader....